# Haskell - Loops in a List

Tags: list, loops, haskell, project

I'm doing a small project in Haskell, and I'm having difficulty in checking if there is a Loop in a `[Moviment]`.

```
data Moviment = goLeft | goRight | Jump | Box
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

> goLeft -> Makes the Player move to the left  goRight -> Makes the
> Player move to the right  Jump -> Makes the Player jump a Box or a
> Block  Box -> Makes the Player load or unload a Box

```
data Piece = Block | Box | Door | Empty
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

At first I created a code where I see if `[goRight, goLeft, goRight]` or `[goLeft, goRight, goLeft]` is in a list of `Moviment`.

```
verificaEliminar :: [Moviment] -> [Moviment] -> Bool
verificaEliminar (x:y:z:[]) l = if(length l < 3)
                                then False
                                else if(x == head l && y == head (tail l) && z == head (tail (tail l)))
                                     then True
                                     else verificaEliminar (x:y:z:[]) (tail l)
verificaEliminar _ _ = False

eliminaLoops :: [[Moviment]] -> [Moviment] -> [[Moviment]]
eliminaLoops (h:t) m = if(verificaEliminar m h == True)
                       then eliminaLoops t m
                       else h : eliminaLoops t m
eliminaLoops _ _ = []
```

But I quickly realised that I could have a Map where I needed to see if the 1st and the 3rd positions of the player are the same. Meaning that he didnot fell.

```
x :: Mapa 
x = [[Bloco, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Bloco, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio], 
     [Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Bloco, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Bloco, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Vazio, Bloco, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio],
     [Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Vazio, Porta, Vazio],
     [Bloco, Bloco, Bloco, Bloco, Bloco, Bloco]]
```

More information if is needed:

```
data Direction = West | East
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

data Player = Player Coordinates Direction Bool
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)

data Game = Game Map Player
  deriving (Read, Eq)

type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
```

[image: Game Example]

Comment: Hey thanks for the details about the current code you've worked on. Could you elaborate a bit further on what exactly the problem you ran into is? It's not clear what help you are asking for in this question

Comment: Hey, I´m having problem in checking if there is a loop in a [Moviment], goRight, go Left and then return again to same sport and doing that N times. For example, I give 10 max opportunities to solve the game (Player go to the door) and the code generates, Jump, goRight, goRight, go Left, goRight, go Left,goRight, go Left meaning that the Player is always returning to a specific position

Answer (score 0):

One plan, in broad strokes, looks like this:

1. Identify all of the state that gets updated by each `Moviment`. Presumably this is `Game`, but I'm not 100% sure of that.
2. Write a function that updates all of the state according to one `Moviment`; let's say you name it `update`, so that

   ```
    update :: Game -> Moviment -> Game
   ```
3. You can use `scanl` to get a list of the `Game`s corresponding to each prefix of a `[Moviment]`.
4. You can now iterate over this `[Game]` looking for two equal states. There are various ways to do this, but take a look at the source of [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#nub) for some hints about one way to do this.

Once you have it working, you can start thinking about refactoring it to improve efficiency. Just switching from the ideas in `nub` to the ideas in [`ordNub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-3.6.2.0/docs/src/Distribution.Utils.Generic.html#ordNub) would be one good first step. You might also consider whether the entire `Mapa` needs to be compared each time or whether you can reduce the amount of comparisons done there somehow. I suspect you can come up with your own ideas, too.